# pasar datos de un componente a otro Angular 6

Tags: angular

si me pudieran ayudar, necesito enviar el valor de una variable de un componente a otro. debo enviar datos desde el componente operator-form a operator-form-next.

[image: imagen]

Comment: Hola Alexander.

Hay varias maneras dependiendo

Answer (score 0):

Hay varias maneras dependiendo, de como este montado la relación entre componentes

- Si son padre e hijo, puedes utilizar **`@Input`** y **`@output`** para realizarlo.
  te adjunto un [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z8L5eRQiO70&list=PLcLoUdtOOXL34dK3xIZaAsc-EEo1O0CGP&index=18)
- Pero si no es el caso, es recomendable utilizar un servicio que sirva los cambios entre componentes, como es un poco largo de explicar [te dejo un enlace](https://medium.com/@javifont/3-formas-de-comunicarse-entre-componentes-angular-b349ada25797)